# write a list to file but error : writelines() argument must be a sequence of strings

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list, and I want to write that list to a file txt

```
lines=[3,5,6]

result = open("result.txt", "w")
result.writelines(lines)
result.close()
```

But when I run, I get the following error:

> writelines() argument must be a sequence of strings

Comment: Ehm, is `lines` a sequence of strings?

Comment: `result.writelines(map(str, lines))`

Comment: @ozgur, with your solution I can resolve the error. But I get in result file 3 5 6 without newline. How to add newline between the data of the list?

Comment: `result.writelines("\n".join(map(str, lines)))`

Comment: @Baris: if you have a string, then just use `file.write(string)`. `file.writelines(string)` will still treat the string as a *sequence*, which I guess will be less efficient.

Comment: Good point, thanks @eugeney!

Answer (score 7):

The error is self-explanatory: you must pass a sequence of *strings*, not numbers to `file.writelines()`. So convert the numbers to strings, and perhaps add newlines:

```
lines = [3, 5, 6]
with open("result.txt", "w") as f:
    f.writelines([str(line) + "\n" for line in lines])
```

Comment: Why keep the brackets in writelines? Even though is it is important to understand that is list comprehension, it is useless in this case.

Comment: Max: both will work, although for small number of items list comprehensions are usually faster than generators.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're giving it a list of integers and it plainly told you it wants a sequence of strings.
It'd just be rude not to oblige:

```
result.writelines(str(line) for line in lines)
```